# Improving screen capture performance

Tags: c, performance, winapi, gdi

I am going to create some kind of "remote desktop" application that streams the content of the screen over a socket to a connected client.

In order to take a screenshot, I've come up with the following piece of code, which is a modified version of examples I've seen here and there.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int _tmain( int argc, _TCHAR * argv[] )
{
    int ScreenX = 0;
    int ScreenY = 0;
    BYTE* ScreenData = 0;

    HDC hScreen = GetDC(GetDesktopWindow());

    ScreenX = GetDeviceCaps(hScreen, HORZRES);
    ScreenY = GetDeviceCaps(hScreen, VERTRES);
    ScreenData = (BYTE*)calloc(4 * ScreenX * ScreenY, sizeof(BYTE) );

    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmi = {0};
    bmi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmi.biPlanes = 1;
    bmi.biBitCount = 32;
    bmi.biWidth = ScreenX;
    bmi.biHeight = -ScreenY;
    bmi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bmi.biSizeImage = 0; // 3 * ScreenX * ScreenY;


    int iBegTc = ::GetTickCount();

    // Take 100 screen captures for a more accurante measurement of the duration.
    for( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i )
    {
        HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreen, ScreenX, ScreenY);
        HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC (hScreen);
        HGDIOBJ hOld = SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);
        BitBlt(hdcMem, 0, 0, ScreenX, ScreenY, hScreen, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        SelectObject(hdcMem, hOld);
        GetDIBits(hdcMem, hBitmap, 0, ScreenY, ScreenData, (BITMAPINFO*)&bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
        DeleteDC(hdcMem);
        DeleteObject(hBitmap);
    }

    int iEndTc = ::GetTickCount();

    printf( "%d ms", (iEndTc - iBegTc) / 100 );
    system("PAUSE");

    ReleaseDC(GetDesktopWindow(),hScreen);

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that the code within the loop takes too long too execute. In my case it's about 36 ms per iteration.

I am wondering if there are statements that could be done just once and thus put outside of the loop, likI did for the byte buffer. I don't know however which are the ones that I must do for each new image, and which are the ones I can only do one time.

Comment: Not sure i get your comment "// Take 100 screen captures for a more accurante measurement of the duration.". I'm pretty sure the first three line of the for loop can probably done outside of the loop no? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well currently I have not tried to change things without knowing first. I suspect that, depending on what mistake I do, I could, for example, have the same screenshot for each iteration due to something not being updated, and because it's not easy to compare the screenshots without actually displaying them, it would be unpractical to just try things blindly.
I'm doing this loop multiple times because I know by experience that GetTickCount is not always very accurate. If it is sometimes inaccurate by 15 ms, then this measurement error is divided by the number of times you iterate.

Comment: Well, sure, but why are you constantly allocating somewhat costly resources (first 3 lines of your loop), instead of reusing them? Not allocating resources is certainly no slower than allocating resources, so this isn't *"blindly trying things"* either.

Comment: As I said in my first comment and I agree with @IInspectable that you could very well try to do the allocation outside of your for loop. It will surely not hurt your implementation. While this may not be enough to get a good enough time performance it will surely improve it. Surely the Delete() could be done outside as well... It's not blindly testing in that case but just trying what seems to be the most logical thing to do.

Comment: That's my point : I wasn't sure about what allocates and what can be done outside of the loop. When the screen gets updated, the DC pointed to by hScreen is also updated ? Btw you say the first three lines. That Implies that I can remove the 5-th line ? Thanks. EDIT : Well for some reason it's now taking an extra 10 ms per iteration after moving the first 3 lines and the last 2 lines outside of the loop and commenting out the 5-th one, strange.

Comment: You should probably read about [Device Contexts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183553.aspx). As for the code changes, we cannot comment on what we cannot see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep `BitBlt` and `GetDIBits` inside the loop, move the rest outside the loop as follows:

```
HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreen, ScreenX, ScreenY);
HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC (hScreen);
HGDIOBJ hOld = SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);

for( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i )
{
    BitBlt(hdcMem, 0, 0, ScreenX, ScreenY, hScreen, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    //hBitmap is updated now
    GetDIBits(hdcMem, hBitmap, 0, ScreenY, ScreenData, (BITMAPINFO*)&bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    //wait...
}

SelectObject(hdcMem, hOld);
DeleteDC(hdcMem);
DeleteObject(hBitmap);
```

In addition `bmi.biSizeImage` should be set to data size, in this case `4 * ScreenX * ScreenY`

This won't make the code noticeably faster. The bottle neck is at `BitBlt`. It's still about 30 frames/sec, this should be okay unless there is a game or movie on the screen.

You might also try saving to a 24 bit bitmap. It won't make any difference in this code but data size would be smaller `((width * bitcount + 31) / 32) * 4 * height)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did something like this, but unfortunately, BitBlt is is what is taking a very large part of the computation time and is too slow for my needs. I'll have to find another way to do this.

Comment: There are other options for example, for DirectX games, but `BitBlt` is the only option for remote desktop as far as I know. You can add hook for mouse and keyboard, take screen shot only after user input, this will greatly improve performance, and it should be okay unless the window is doing some drawings on its own.

Answer (score 0):

The Aero feature of Windows seems to affect the BitBlt speed.

If you iteratively BitBlt even one pixel from the display, it will run at about 30 frames per second, and the CPU usage will be near idle. But if you turn off the Aero feature of Windows, you'll get BitBlt speeds that are remarkably faster.